# Multiarch Build System

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I am trying to understand the multiarch Makefile based build system found in opensource projects such as linux [kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source), [glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc) and so on. In all of these projects the source code is organized as C/C++ modules(e.g. filesystem, networking, logging) etc, generic headers such as include/ and then arch specific directory tree (arch/{x86,mips,arm}) etc. I want to understand how to layout of such projects is formed what specific language constructs and techniques are used to map the highlevel C routines to their arch specific implementations. I had tried to look around on the internet and didn't find information covering exactly this subject or introducing how to layout and design the Makefiles, organize C and assembly so that the build system correctly creates the build.

For a concrete example, lets consider the glibc, which utilizes a macro [HP_TIMING_NOW](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/9a869d822025be8e43b78234997b10bf0cf9d859/sysdeps/generic/hp-timing.h#L72) whose implementation differs for different architectures ([x86_64](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/9a869d822025be8e43b78234997b10bf0cf9d859/sysdeps/x86_64/hp-timing.h#L25), [powerpc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/9a869d822025be8e43b78234997b10bf0cf9d859/sysdeps/powerpc/powerpc64/hp-timing.h#L88)...).

I do understand that the whole build system works through invoking make recursively but may understanding of this process is superficial and I am looking for some concrete explanation in the form of resources or answers to cover this subject.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question may be closed as [too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it). It touches at least two huge topics: "How to write a build system" and "What code is platform dependent?" It's topic for a few books. You may want to read the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Only one folder under _arch/_ is being accessed from _Makefile_. This is done by attaching a variable (`ARCH`) contents to the pathname. I was talking about Linux kernel, but the idea is the same for all of them.

Comment: @VictorSergienko I am not asking a crisp and rich in detail response equivalent to a book. I am looking either someone with the right knowledge should point to a right resource maybe a specific book, talk or a writeup. Certainly 0andriy comment was helpful. However closing a question as a mod ceases possibility of finding an answer. Often a short but relevant answer is enough for the questioner and deem acceptable. I suggest you to reopen it.

Comment: I am not a mod and I didn't (vote to) close it. I'm just pointing out that SO has a certain rules, and questions need to follow them. Opinion-based and recommendation questions are off topic, and this question is both. I suggest you break it in smaller questions, maybe, on other SE sites like programmers.stackexchange.